# Django models: foriegn key or multiple data in a field

Tags: django, model

Actually, this question has puzzled me for a long time.

Say, I have two models, `Course` and `CourseDate`, as follows:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField()

class CourseDate(models.Model):
    course = modelds.ForienKey(Course)
    date = models.DateField()
```

where `CourseDate` is the dates that a certain course will take place.

I could also define `Course` as follows and discard `CourseDate`:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    dates = models.CharField()
```

where the `dates` field contains dates represented by strings. For example:

```
dates = '2016-10-1,2016-10-12,2016-10-30'
```

I don't know if the second solution is kind of "cheating". So, which one is better?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about cheating, but it certainly goes against good database design. More to the point, it prevents you from doing almost all kinds of useful queries on that field. What if you wanted to know all courses that had dates within two days of a specific date? Almost impossible to do that with solution 2, but simple with solution 1.